# saving data for WCF Service in Windows Azure - very basic

Tags: wcf, azure

I have a few (small size) tables, saved in Table Storage which I use only for reading from. 
When my service starts, I'd like to read all tables, save the data in a data structure (i.e. List), and read from that List from there on.
Is there a way to do that, or must I read from the Table Storage each time I need data?
If there is a way, where should the List be declared, and where should it be initialized?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure cache may be the best route, but there is an obvious cost.

Could you declare the WCF service as a singleton and store the data as a static property?

Comment: you don't need to be singleton to store the data in a static property. just need to have a static constructor (a.k.a. type initializer) to fill up the static property, and never change it back. Then it does not matter how many instance you have, you will still have the static property of the type and use it.

Comment: Used a static property. Seems to work well :) Thanks astaykov

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Windows Azure Cache service to store the data.  See http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/tour/caching/

Answer (score 0):

If your list is not too big, you could use the Windows Azure caching component http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/tour/caching/ . During the initialization process of your service, read the information from your tables, and stored it there. You are also asking where the list should declared and initialized. Are you also hosting your service on Windows Azure? Is this a web service runnig on IIS, or a windows service? Are you using WCF to expose your service?

Answer (score 0):

I see others are suggesting static properties (good choice) and Azure Chache. Anyway it is good to cache the data if it is not often updated, and not read it every time from the Table Storage.

I want to give my two cents:

I would not use Azure Cahce if the data is small enough (1MB is small enough for me). Static property would do the work. But there is also something new to .NET 4.0 and obviously missing from most of programmes view. It's the [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd985642.aspx) namespace. I haven't presonally used it yet, but it seems to be a good for small local caches. You could use the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) object and store your data in-memory. And, of course program like against any other type of chache - in the getter of a property, check if data exists in the chache. If exists - return it. If does not exists - retrieve from tables, store in chache, and then return it.